# Excluding some classes from the cobertura report doesn't work

Tags: cobertura

I tried to remove some classes from the cobertura report as

```
<target name="voldemort-instrument" description="Instrument Voldemort Classes">
        <mkdir dir="${voldemort.instrumented.dir}" />
        <cobertura-instrument todir="${voldemort.instrumented.dir}" datafile="${cobertura.instrument.file}">
            <classpath refid="tools-classpath" />
            <ignore regex=".*\.xsd" />
            <fileset dir="${voldemort.dist.dir}/classes">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
                <exclude name="**/client/protocol/pb/*.class"/>
                <exclude name="**/server/http/*.class"/>
                <exclude name="**/server/http/gui/*.class"/>
                <exclude name="**/store/views/*.class"/>
                <exclude name="**/store/gzip/*.class"/>
                <exclude name="**/VoldemortClientShell.class"/>
                <exclude name="**/ClusterViewer.class"/>   
                <exclude name="**/utils/VoldemortAdminClientShell*.class"/>  
            </fileset>
        </cobertura-instrument>
    </target>
```

But this doesn't work.....

Do I need to change something else too..

Please help me, I am struggling with this for past 1 week....

Comment: Link to question where it was resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066873/excluding-plugins-from-cobertura-reports-in-grails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven cobertura plugin, does not respect exclude tags for report generation.
This is a known bug reportrted here:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-52

Comment: Link to duplicate question by me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217907/ignoring-report-generation-for-specific-classes-in-cobertura-maven-plugin/5307993#5307993