# Excluding plugins from Cobertura reports in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spring-security, cobertura

I'm using SpringSecurity plugin in my project and also Cobertura plugin for code coverage reports. The thing is I'd like the SpringSecurity specific classes (login and logout controllers, persistent login token and so on) to be excluded from my reports, since I assume they work properly. I'd like reports to contain only my project specific classes code coverage. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
coverage {

    exclusions = ['**/grails-app/conf/**','**/*any.other.package*','**/*any.class*']
    xml = true
    enabledByDefault = true
}
```

Add the above snippet and configure the exclusions list in BuildConfig.groovy in grails-app/conf

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Exclude code from code coverage with Cobertura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951569/exclude-code-from-code-coverage-with-cobertura)

There is a similar post [Excluding some classes from the cobertura report doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966061/excluding-some-classes-from-the-cobertura-report-doesnt-work), but it is still unresolved.